# Energy conversions in Electric furnace

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electricity, electric-current

Heating furnaces use eddy current to work, but I have a problem understanding something, what are the energy conversions that happen in the electric furnace? Is it magnetic->electric->thermal or is it electric->magnetic->thermal

What is eddy current considered as here? Is it a magnetic energy or electric energy?

Not a homework question just a question to understand the electric furnace better

Comment: Most electrical heaters are straightforward resistive heating, no eddy currents required. What kind of a furnace are you looking at?

Comment: Something like this i mean https://i.ibb.co/98N5hLn/C64-F5-EB2-3-D81-4616-9-B3-D-405772-CF1-F4-C.png  @JonCuster

Comment: So, an induction heater. Yes, the eddy currents are important as noted in the answer by @nielsnielsen

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current - the eddy currents are induced in the metal, lose energy through resistance, and thereby heat the metal crucible. This allows you to use a replaceable metal crucible made out of a variety of different metals, depending on what you want to melt.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @JonCuster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrical power is used in a coil of wire in the heating oven to produce a time-varying magnetic field.

That magnetic field induces a time-varying electric current to flow in the metal being melted.

That current flowing through the metal dissipates electrical power as ohmic heating in the metal.

The ohmic heating increases the temperature of the metal.

Comment: So basically electric energy preceeds the thermal energy being produced right?  And isn’t the current flowing in the metal that dissipates electric power eddy current? @nielsnielsen

Comment: @Flora561, yes and yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @nielsnielsen

Answer (score 1):

I think (electric+magnetic)->thermal.

Electromagnetic energy is transmitted by the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector), which is composed of electric field and magnetic field. Even low frequency electric power lines (2-wire AC or 3-phase AC), the electromagnetic energy is not transmitted through metal lines, but is transmitted by Poynting vector in insulating material including space (vacuum) between metal lines.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @HEMMI